# MAX of mapped criteria unless another value is lower

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254803/mapping-value-if-it-matches-criteria-excel) question in the past.  What I need to do now is List Dan's Bakery in the Entity final column.  The original entities go through a mapping table and the MAX limit is in the Limit final column.  Here is that formula, `{=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($G$2:$G$110,IF('Mapping Table'!$B$4:$B$204=B25,'Mapping Table'!$A$4:$A$204),0)),$D$2:$D$110))}`.  In the above formula, the lookup value for Match is the Parent Connection (G) column and the mapping table maps any entities with certain names to a parent and the D column would be the Limit 1 as there is a hidden column.  Hope that's clear enough.

I want to now write a similar formula so that whichever Entity has the highest limit and **WORST** risk rating is shown in the Entity final column.  Meaning, in the below example, Dan's Groceries would be the entity I want to produce in the Entity final column because it has a credit limit line of 30 and a better rating (the lower the rating, the better).  Any ideas?

**EDIT** **(March 21)** :  I need a formula that will take into account the mapping it will register the above formula as well as take into the account the ratings.

[image]

I changed the formula to,
`=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH(MIN((1-IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$D$1:$D$7)/MIN(IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$D$1:$D$7)))+IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$C$1:$C$7)/MAX(IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$C$1:$C$7))),(1-$D$1:$D$7/MIN(IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$D$1:$D$7)))+IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$C$1:$C$7)/MAX(IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$C$1:$C$7)),0))`

but, I am coming across errors. For example, if I changed the Limit column for Other to 30, `Dan's Bakery` is the result or when I change `Dan's Shakes limit to 40 (assuming it will be the correct`Final Entity`it seems to be taking the MIN rating as the ultimate decider with`Dan's Fuel` still as the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your `Limit` and `Rating` worth the same you can scale them to values between `0` and `1`. After that simple addition would rate one of Entities as the "winner".

Here is example data and an array formula that can do what you want(Array Formulas are applied with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`:

Data:

```
A               B   C
Dan's Shakes    25  3
Dan's Groceries 30  2   
Dan's Floral    10  2   
Dan's Bakery    30  1   
Dan's Fuel      20  4
```

Formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(MAX((1-C1:C5/MAX(C1:C5))+B1:B5/MAX(B1:B5)),(1-C1:C5/MAX(C1:C5))+B1:B5/MAX(B1:B5),0))
```

Outcome:

```
A               B   C   D
Dan's Shakes    25  3   Dan's Bakery
Dan's Groceries 30  2   
Dan's Floral    10  2   
Dan's Bakery    30  1   
Dan's Fuel      20  4
```

**EDIT:**

And when you introduce a parent your data would look like this:

```
A               B           C   D    
Dan's Shakes    Dan Corp    25  3
Dan's Groceries Dan Corp    30  2
Dan's Floral    Dan Corp    10  2
Dan's Bakery    Dan Corp    30  1
Dan's Fuel      Dan Corp    20  4
Something Else  Bob Corp    30  2
Other           Bob Corp    50  1
```

Your array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH(MAX((1-IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$D$1:$D$7)/MAX(IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$D$1:$D$7)))+IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$C$1:$C$7)/MAX(IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$C$1:$C$7))),(1-$D$1:$D$7/MAX(IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$D$1:$D$7)))+IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$C$1:$C$7)/MAX(IF($B$1:$B$7=B1,$C$1:$C$7)),0))
```

Result:

```
A               B           C   D   E
Dan's Shakes    Dan Corp    25  3   Dan's Bakery
Dan's Groceries Dan Corp    30  2   Dan's Bakery
Dan's Floral    Dan Corp    10  2   Dan's Bakery
Dan's Bakery    Dan Corp    30  1   Dan's Bakery
Dan's Fuel      Dan Corp    20  4   Dan's Bakery
Something Else  Bob Corp    30  2   Other
Other           Bob Corp    50  1   Other
```

Comment: this is great but, I would need a formula that maps the Entities to the correct parent and then takes into account the ratings.  Sorry if that wasn't clear earlier.  I have added corrected version of the table where the formula would go into the Entity Final column

Comment: What is the `parent` in your data?

Comment: The connector is the parent.

Comment: in the answer above, is there a way for the result to be Dan's Groceries?  I guess I am looking for the inverse.  If the total in column C is the same, I would want column E to show the lesser value (in the above example, 2)  Sorry, I have been playing around with it and I can't figure it out.